# Transfer learning for audio

Tags: lstm, transfer-learning, speech-recognition, gru

I know that when working with images, what people normally do is download a big model trained with huge data and freeze most of the layers except the lasts ones to train them with their own data.

I'm wondering if the same could be done when working with audio, I mean have a model with maybe a couple of recurrent layers (LSTM, GRU or whatever) that would be good at generalizing some types of audio (Maybe only for speech or music). Would that be possible? 
Why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such models exist for sure, for example Google provides pretrained audioset model trained on huge amount of audio data and this model helps to build audio classification with transfer learning, see

https://research.google.com/audioset/download.html

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/audioset

Answer (score 0):

Google has published a tutorial for TensorFlow.js that demonstrates transfer learning with a pretrained model for speech command recognition:
https://www.tensorflow.org/js/tutorials/transfer/audio_recognizer